# Can I change my current_schema as an alias?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 2 simply Questions.
First I want to change my schema i show You.

```
alter session set current_schema=uauktion as auktion;
```

Second this code dont work and i dont know why it does not work.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT=’DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS’;
```

Comment: try this:  alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'

Comment: it works ty so much^^

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the quotes on your date format string.
Following should work:

```
     ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

Comment: Did you know how can i put an alias into the schema name

Comment: You want your current_schema to be changed to a different user, which will be a vairbale, is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

### You should write like this

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
```

and you do not give an alias. you can give another schema

```
alter session set current_schema=uauktion ;
```